# Django - Custom ModelAdmin form not overriding default models

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeladmin

I have a model defined

```
class subnet(models.Model):
subnet_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
subnet_pod = models.ForeignKey(pod, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Select Pod')
subnet_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='VLAN/SVI Number')
subnet_description = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Subnet Description')
LAYER_CHOICES = (
    ('Layer2', 'Layer2'),
    ('Layer3', 'Layer3'),
)
subnet_layer = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LAYER_CHOICES,verbose_name='Layer2/3')
subnet_ip = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Gateway IP/Mask')
vrf = models.ForeignKey(vrf,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Select VRF')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Subnet'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Subnets'

def __str__(self):
    return self.subnet_number
```

I want to override the subnet_ip and add a label and placeholder to it using a custom form, so I have:

```
class subnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = subnet
    fields = ['subnet_number', 'subnet_description', 'subnet_layer', 'vrf']
    widgets = {
        'subnet_ip': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e.g,: x.x.x.x/x'}),
    }
```

However the placeholder does not get applied to the model and does not show in front-end.

I also have a admin.py:

```
class subnetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('subnet_number','subnet_description','subnet_layer','subnet_ip','vrf')
ordering = ('-subnet_number',)
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
class subnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
   subnet_number = <use same model field datatype> forms.CharField(label = 'subnet_number', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder' : 'subnet number'}))
   class Meta:
       model = subnet
       fields = ['subnet_number', __other_fields__]
```

Comment: That did not work. The field which needs a placeholder is subnet_ip though. I tried :
`class subnetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subnet_ip = forms.CharField(label = 'subnet_ip', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder' : 'Test'}))
    class Meta:
       model = subnet
       fields = ['subnet_ip','subnet_number', 'subnet_description', 'subnet_layer', 'vrf']`